# Converting string macros/constants to wide characters/Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar, c-preprocessor

I have a Unicode Win32 application that uses 3rd party libraries, some of which provide constants for their version information as #defined (narrow) strings.   For instance, [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) has the following:

```
#define PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING "1.5.4"
#define PNG_HEADER_VERSION_STRING \
 " libpng version 1.5.4 - July 7, 2011\n"
```

I'm appending the various *statically* linked libraries version information to my About Box for easy version tracking, and it seemed like it would be simple to convert this constant into a wide string.

My first attempt was TEXT(PNG_HEADER_VERSION_STRING), but that fails as

```
#define __TEXT(quote) L##quote
```

.. and LPNGHEADER_VERSION_STRING doesn't exist of course.

So I tried several combinations of double wrapping macros, and all sorts of ## tricks to attempt to add the L prefix to a macro'ed constant, but wasn't able to.    Am I missing something simple?  How would you handle:

```
#define VERSIONSTR "Test V1.2.3"
const char* ver= VERSIONSTR;
const wchar* wver = _T(VERSIONSTR); // fails, should be L"Test V1.2.3"
#define VERSIONSTRW _T(VERSIONSTR);  // fails also
```

programmatically, without simply adding a duplicate L"Test V1.2.3" and having to keep it in sync with the 3rd party library.

I know I can just convert it at runtime if I'm building for Unicode, but I thought surely there was a quick way to re-define this constant.

**---UPDATE---**

I missed the plot by doing something really stupid with my include structure.   Fixing that allowed the double define wrapper to function as it should.   Stupid on my part.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  `#define VERSIONSTRW _T(VERSIONSTR)` works for me in VC++ 2008.

Comment: VS2003.  I know its old, but its currently required.   Perhaps its just a bug in my compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to use two macros. When a macro is expanded, the arguments are macro-expanded before being substituted into the replacement list. So `WIDEN(VERSIONSTR)` becomes `WIDEN2("Test V1.2.3")`.

```
#define WIDEN(quote) WIDEN2(quote)
#define WIDEN2(quote) L##quote

#define VERSIONSTR "Test V1.2.3"
#define VERSIONSTRW WIDEN(VERSIONSTR)
```

Comment: I had tried that previously.  VS fails with the same error as before they were single wrapped.  wchar *str = WIDEN(VERSIONSTR) results in error C2065: 'LVERSIONSTR' : undeclared identifier

Comment: See my update.  The double macro trick works fine in VS2003 (and later I assume).  My stupidity kept me from seeing the obvious.